# Best practice to validate Akka Persistence commands

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

Let's say we have a command `AddUser`:

```
case class AddUser(username: String, password: String)
```

What would be the best way to validate this command before you persist an event?
Doing it in a way like this for example, seems kind of messy.

```
override def receiveCommand: Receive = {
    case AddUser(username, password) =>
      if (username.trim.length > 25) {
        sender() ! UsernameTooLong
      } else if (password.trim.length > 25) {
        sender() ! PasswordTooLong
      } else {
        persist(UserAdded(User(username, password))) {
          userAdded =>
            sender() ! userAdded
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Receive Pipeline Pattern: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/contrib/receive-pipeline.html

you can do something like this:

```
trait AuthenticatedUser { this: ReceivePipeline =>
   pipelineInner {
    case msg@AddUser(username, password) => 
     if (username.trim.length > 25) {
        sender() ! UsernameTooLong
     } else if (password.trim.length > 25) {
        sender() ! PasswordTooLong
     } else {
       Inner(msg)
     }
   case msg => Inner(msg)
   }
}

class UserActor extends Actor with ReceivePipeline with AuthenticatedUser {

 def receive = {
   case AddUser(username, password) =>
    persist(UserAdded(User(username, password))) {
          userAdded =>
            sender() ! userAdded
        }
  }
}
```

PS: I have not compiled and tested this code, But I believe it will work, If there is any issue let me know.

Comment: Yes. That works quite well. Except, you have to replace `sender() ! UsernameTooLong` with `Inner(UsernameTooLong)`. Also, I guess that you can extend `AuthenticatedUser` with `ReceivePipeline` and then extend `UserActor` only with `AuthenticatedUser` trait. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: `ReceivePipeline` is now deprecated